# How to pull updated data only on Mobile App?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, firebase, xamarin

### Case

I have an app where I am downloading information about some products from a server and storing it to an SQLite database.

Every minute I re-download the whole information in case it has been modified, deleted or added although I know it is not efficient.

### Goal

What I need is some form of getting only the data that has been modified if it actually has.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: typically you would include the timestamp of the last update in your request, and your server would only return data that changed since that timestamp

Comment: @Jason how to notify the clients when data has changed?

Comment: That is a completely different question than what you asked.  You already stated the client was checking for updates every minute.  If you want to notify the client of changes, look into something like SignalR.

Comment: syncing, especially if it's bi-directional, is non-trivial. I'd recommend you leverage what App Center provides for Xamarin Mobile Apps (if you're not married to Firebase), read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/data/

Comment: Generally speaking, *polling*, which is what you're describing, is super inefficient and a vast waste of resources. It will also burn up your users cell phone batteries. You would be much better off leveraging a database that handles presenting fresh data for you. Your question is tagged Firebase so you should really look into [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/). Other than that, this is a very opinion type question which is somewhat broad.

Comment: @Jay So what is the good practice to handle this situation? should we implement realtime approch like SignalR or Websocket for that?

Comment: You should explore the Cloud Firestore link in my above comment as that is a solution to the presented problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions for this problem. No one here will be able to give a conclusive answer without knowing your system in more. But following is a possible approach that might work for you.

1. Client side need to cache/save the timestamp of when the api was last called.
2. Server need to make changes to the existing api, to send the timestamp. If there is any changes made to the data since the timestamp, the server will return those changes or else no data.

Another approach will be to have a data sync, which will be more efficient but it involves more complexity and there might be more work involved.